# How to update k-ng-model (a.k.a. two-way binding like with ng-model)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, kendo-ui, telerik

Does Kendo `k-ng-model` support two-way binding, and if not, what is the best approach to simulate it?

---

*A bit of context:*

In angular, when an update to ng-model is done, all interested parties are updated (e.g. view is refreshed). In kendo, when using k-ng-model, I cannot find a way of doing the same, where I would want to set the value from the controller / directive directly.

Here is an example: [Coding Dojo](http://dojo.telerik.com/@DenisB/AmaLI)

And, just in case, the code as well:

```
 <input kendo-auto-complete 
        k-ng-model="vm.kendoSelection" 
        ng-model="vm.angularSelection"                     
        k-data-source="vm.countryNames" 
        k-data-value-field="'name'"
        k-data-text-field="'name'" />
```

sample controller:

```
  angular.module("MyApp", [ "kendo.directives" ])
         .controller("Controller", function(){                  
             // just some data source
             this.countryNames = [
                { name: "Albania" },
                { name: "Andorra" }
              ];

             // how to set the k-ng-model here, so that it is also propagated properly (like on 
             // the view, and that other events like k-on-change work)?
             this.kendoSelection = { name: "Albania" };                  
          });
```

---

**EDIT:**

Even after the answer from Dion Dirza, the k-on-change is not firing (altough it is a solution in good direction)

[Example with k-on-change](http://dojo.telerik.com/@DenisB/AmaLI/4)

Dion Dirza

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As documentation said, that `k-ng-model` should store or return actual type of widget value. Therefore to make your variable `kendoSelection` work, you should define it as **actual type of widget value**, which in this case is array type for auto-complete widget.

Change your code

`vm.kendoSelection = [{ name: "Albania" }];`

Because you are storing object array here so your variable should be array of object. Put a caution here that your object should contains a property that defined as widget **data-value-field** which it will be used for comparison with current data source.

Comment: trouble is, k-on-change is still not firing, but yes this is a move in good direction.

Comment: in this [dojo](http://dojo.telerik.com/EwALa) k-on-change works perfectly.. Whats your problem? Maybe put another question for different context.

Comment: when setting from "code behind" the vm.kendoSelection, the k-on-change is fired for you?http://dojo.telerik.com/@DenisB/AmaLI/4

Comment: you don't mention it was "programmatically" before, well yes change event can't be triggered  with that, as [documentation](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/multiselect#events-change) noted that also. You can add [$watch](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watch) for it.